# how do I find elements that contain a data-* attribute matching a prefix using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm want to create a selector to find elements which have attributes starting with a string. At this point, I'm assuming this selector does not exist.
Do I need to extend the selector capabilities? [Extending jQuery’s selector capabilities](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/extending-jquerys-selector-capabilities/) by James Padolsey

I need to express something like the Attribute Contains Prefix Selector [name|="value"], but instead of matching "value", I need to match against the name of the attribute, and not the value of the attribute.

`<tag data-plugin-option1="val1" data-plugin-option2="val2" />`

I'd like to end up with a syntax like this:
`$('tag(:attr|="data-plugin")')` which should find the element `tag` because it has at least one element that starts with `data-plugin`

Comment: I think `.data()` parses these automatically, although it might have been just in HTML 5, I can't remember right now

Comment: @Pekka: I think OP is looking for a selector that returns *elements* which have a matching attribute name (or partial name).

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for a selector that returns elements.

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ, good point. I deleted my answer and up-voted yours.

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ, also it's not easy to @-quote you in a comment. I had to copy-and-paste your name.

Comment: @BenLee: *"also it's not easy to @-quote you"* Yes, I know. ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, I guess I'm reading your question differently.

The way I read it, you want to create a custom selector that selects elements that have a given attribute name (or the start of that name).

If so, I think you'd need to iterate of the `attributes` collection for each element.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/GgmM7/

```
$.extend($.expr[':'],{
    attrNameStart: function(el,i,props) {

        var hasAttribute = false;

        $.each( el.attributes, function(i,attr) {
            if( attr.name.indexOf( props[3] ) !== -1 ) {
                hasAttribute = true;
                return false;  // to halt the iteration
            }
        });

        return hasAttribute;
    }
});
```

---

```
$('img:attrNameStart(data-plugin)')
```

Comment: that's some beautiful code. I'm not sure why I'm so  absent minded that I forgot about the `attributes` property on a dom element. thanks so much!