# Find elements which contains part of an attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm having some trouble to find a selector which can match the following:

```
$("input[data-rule-*]");
```

So, if i have `data-rule-required` or `data-rule-email`, both of the attributes need to be matched. (only examples, i have a bunch of suffixes, specify all of them is not an option).

I've found only `$("#element[attribute=value]")` selectors, which doesn't satisfy my condition.

I took a look at this topic: [how do I find elements that contain a data-* attribute matching a prefix using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602410/how-do-i-find-elements-that-contain-a-data-attribute-matching-a-prefix-using-j). The question is the same, but i'd like to know if there's a more compact solution.

HTML example. Assuming that i can have a lot more inputs with distinct `data-rule-something` attributes:

```
<div>
    <label for="field1" class="control-label">Field 1</label>
    <input maxlength="4" data-inputmask="'mask':'9999'" data-rule-required="true" id="field1" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0123"></input>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="field2" class="control-label">Conta Corrente</label>
    <input maxlength="14" data-rule-range="5,10" data-inputmask-regex="[0-9]{14}" id="field2" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0123456"></input>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="field3"></label>
    <input maxlength="2" data-rule-email="true" data-inputmask-regex="[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}" id="field3" type="text" class="form-control text-uppercase" placeholder="00"></input>
</div>
```

Comment: is there something hindering you from just adding a single class that would group all those data-rule type elements and then calling that one class?

Comment: Why does your example not work?

Comment: @indubitablee well, indeed is a clean and nice solution, but using classes to non-CSS purposes doesn't sound good at this project (some strange standard not defined by the developers, sure)

Comment: @Mark this yields the following error at Chrome:

"Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[data-rule-*]"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I find elements that contain a data-\* attribute matching a prefix using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602410/how-do-i-find-elements-that-contain-a-data-attribute-matching-a-prefix-using-j)

Comment: Marking this as a duplicate as I'm pretty sure there is no more compact / elegant solution than the one linked to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your options are either to add another attribute or identifier to the elements so you can select them all, or to include all the attribute combinations in your query selector.

The example below adds an additional `data-object` singleton to the two `input` elements, then queries for that attribute to update the field values.

```js
var dataObjects = document.querySelectorAll("[data-object]");
for(var i = 0, len = dataObjects.length; i < len; i++){
  dataObjects[i].value = i;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" data-rule-required data-object />
<input type="text" data-rule-email data-object />
```

Comment: Assuming that is no way to do what i expected, this is the closest solution for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One not so elegant way, but it seems that it is working:

```
$("input").filter(function() {

   if(Object.keys($(this).data()).toString().indexOf('rule')!==-1) {

    return $(this);
   }
}).css('background-color','red');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8x05bh2v/